# RegEx for mining XML tag content

Tags: regex, xml, xpath, notepad++

Fellow Forum Members,
I am using the latest NotePad++. I have 430 separate XML files and my goal is to make a "dmcode" list of all 430 XML files. The dmcode identifies each XML file and looks like the example code shown below. I need help in developing a Regular Expression that will grab the dmcode tag content located between the `<dmCode` opening tag and the closing `/>` terminator. Also I only need this extraction to only apply to dmcode tags that follows the  `<dmIdent>`  tag.  In other words, any dmcode tag that is not preceded by a `<dmIdent>` tag does not end up on my NotePad++ search result list. Is such a Regular Expression that can pull targeted data from a lot of XML files possible?

`<dmIdent>
<dmCode assyCode="00" disassyCode="00" disassyCodeVariant="00" infoCode="042" infoCodeVariant="A" itemLocationCode="O" modelIdentCode="SASA" subSubSystemCode="6" subSystemCode="0" systemCode="A03" systemDiffCode="XY"/>`

As an alternative I have been researching using an XPath expression to accomplish the same task. However, I can't seem to find a NotePad++ XPath plugin that will enable me to specify the data I want to extract from 430 XML files by using an XPath expression instead of a Regular Expression. I will also appreciate it if anyone can provide an example of an XPath expression that will perform the same task I'm trying to accomplish by using a Regular Expression.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I know there are plugins for XPath, but I don't know one that allows you to search several files. The following XPath would match all attributes in `<dmCode>` as a child of the root element `<dmIdent>`:

```
/dmIdent/dmCode[@*]
```

---

> I need help in developing a Regular Expression that will grab the dmcode tag content located between the `<dmCode` opening tag and the closing `/>` terminator. Also I only need this extraction to only apply to `dmCode` tags that follow the `<dmIdent>` tag.

This will work for the most simple cases, where:

- `<dmCode>` is the first child of `<dmIdent>`
- There are no comments, CDATA tags, or similar constructs that could make it fail.

```
(?i)<dmIdent>\s*<dmCode \K[^"/>]*(?>(?:"[^\\"]*(?:\\.[^\\"]*)*"|/(?!>))[^"/>]*)*(?=/>)
```

<kbd>[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/sB9gE2/2)</kbd>

---

Matches:

- `(?i)<dmIdent>\s*<dmCode` both tags spearated by whitespace (case-insensitively)
- `\K` resets the matched text
- `[^"/>]*` Any characters except `"`, `/` or `>`
- And loops:

  - `"[^\\"]*(?:\\.[^\\"]*)*"` text in quotes, or
  - `/(?!>)` a `/` not followed by `>`
  - both followed by the previous `[^"/>]*`
- `(?=/>)` All followed by `/>`